# What is the best way to learn Iris completely independently

Tags: coq, proof-assistant

I am looking forward to learning Iris by myself, I have essential basic knowledge of Coq and logic but I don't know where to start. Logically, I looked into materials on the project website; the video tutorials are too brief, the lecture notes are almost incomplete without explanation, and to me "Iris from the ground up" paper requires lots of prior knowledge since I can't make sense of the syntax that is used there. 
For someone who has no help what can be the best way to start learning Iris by himself?

Comment: I took the Semantics course (https://plv.mpi-sws.org/semantics-course/). Of course, it's different when you attend a lecture (and have someone explain things to you) but I still find these lecture notes great. They have explanations, exercises, and a Coq development that also has exercises.

Comment: @JoJoModding Sorry I ask this question here but I guess it would be dumb to open a thread for this. do you know what coding language the examples are in, (e.g fig 2 in Iris from ground up paper). it is not ML or any other language I'm familiar of.

Comment: As usual in foundations, the programming language used does not really matter. And since real programming languages are often messy, you instead use a simplified version. The language used in the lecture notes is introduced in them. It is a version of System F + State + Recursive Types. You could also say it's pseudo code. If you know any functional language, you should have no trouble understanding it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specifically for Iris, one useful resource is [the POPL'21 tutorial](https://gitlab.mpi-sws.org/iris/tutorial-popl21). It remains terse for a self-studying newcomer however.

If you are not in a rush getting up to speed with Iris specifically, you may want to start with [Arthur Chargueraud's book in the Software Foundation series](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/slf-current/index.html).

It will introduce a number of concepts at a gentler pace, building up a foundational separation logic for a sequential language. Once you are confortable with this, scaling up to the concurrent and higher order fancy features of Iris may be easier.